# Extracting text before first slash "/" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, string, regular-expression

I have a database of motorway junctions which are named like this:

- M90 J8/A91/B996
- M90 J1/A90/A921/A985(T)
- M9 J1A

There is significant variability in the length of the strings but they all follow the same basic pattern of Motorway ID Junction Number / Link Road IDs

How do I extract everything before the first forward slash i.e. the Motorway ID and Junction Number?

- M90 J8
- M90 J1
- M9 J1A

I've been trying to use `regex_substr` based on other answers on here like this: `regexp_substr( "NAME", '^(.+)/')` but this extracts everything before the **last** forwardslash. How can I alter it to get the text before the first slash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This turns out to be doable without using the regex_substr function. Instead the code

```
left( "Name", strpos( "Name" ,'/'))`
```

can be used instead. It works by identifying the string position of the first `/` and then extracting the text to the left of that position.

If anyone has any suggestions regarding regex_substr I'd still like to see them though.

Answer (score 10):

QGIS' regex engine doesn't support non greedy matches (yet), so it'll always return the longest possible match. Try

```
regexp_substr( "NAME", '^[^/]+')
```

That should return all characters from the start of the string which aren't /s.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where in QGIS you want this feature work. If In the field calculator you may define a custom function based on the Python function `split()`.

This image shows the basic definition of such a function. `split('/')[0]` always returns the text before the first occurrence of '/' or the complete string, if no '/' is found.

[image: split function definition]

You can use this new function like this:

[image: usage of split function]

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I was trying to extract tags in OSM-derived shapefiles. I'd like to extract English names, so I tried the following:

```
regexp_substr("other_tags",'"name:en"=>"(.+)"')
```

It returned a huge string after `=>"`, which meant a **greedy** match.
However when I used the following regular expression:

```
regexp_substr("other_tags",'"name:en"=>"(.+?)"')
```

It returned a **lazy** match.
Later when I was discovering Qt's Documentation (QGIS is based on Qt), I found that the greediness of quantifiers like `?` can be [inverted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#details), which may be QGIS's case. Although it still needs to be proven by source code, it's still worth noticing that `?` in QGIS may function like a "**lazy mark**".
Therefore, `^(.+?)\/` could be the answer, thanks to Nathan W. (The `\/` actually means `/`, and `\` is an escape character. )

Comment: The answer by Aurus worked for me, using the +? limited the result to the fist word. I needed the first word prior to the first space so used, ^(.+?)\\s

Comment: For your information, if you want to work `other_tags` which is an HStore field, it's now natively managed by QGIS 3.4: `map_get(htsore_to_map("other_tags"), 'name:en')`

Comment: @etrimaille Thank you for a more efficient approach!