# Regex_replace in the Field Calculator: unexpected duplication of replacement elements

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgsexpression, regular-expression

After testing things out for a [different question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398407/qgis-inserting-strings-with-the-field-calculator/398412?noredirect=1#comment652348_398412), I found something unexpected about the way regex_replace works in the Field Calculator, compared to PostgreSQL. The suggested insert ends up duplicated in the output.

```
The string: 'a_a_a_a_a'.
The desired output: 'a_a_a_a_ca'
```

I'm testing with two patterns. The first finds all the non-underscore characters at the end of a string, while the second finds the first non-underscore character after the fourth underscore. The patterns:

```
([^_]*)$
(?<=[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_)([^_]{1})
```

PostgreSQL regex_replace behaviour works as I would expect:

```sql
select string,
regexp_replace(string,'([^_]*)$','c\1') as repl_1,
regexp_replace(string,'(?<=[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_)([^_]){1}','c\1') as repl_2
from (select 'a_a_a_a_a' as string) pattern
```

Outcome:

| string | repl_1 | repl_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_a_a_a_a | a_a_a_a_ca | a_a_a_a_ca |

Field Calculator behaves differently, using the same pattern:

[image: 2]

`regexp_replace('a_a_a_a_a','([^_]*)$','c')`, as shown by the Output preview, gives `'a_a_a_a_cc'`. Interestingly, the capture group doesn't even have to be called with `\1` to get that output.

When I do call the capture group, I again end up getting an unexpected result:

[image: 3]

`regexp_replace('a_a_a_a_a','([^_]*)$','c\\1') returns 'a_a_a_a_cac'`

Using the positive lookbehind in the Field Calculator works fine, however:

[image: 4]

`regexp_replace('a_a_a_a_a','(?<=[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_[^_]_)([^_]{1})','c\\1')`

Returning `'a_a_a_a_ca'` as expected.

Is this just a weird bug with regex_replace in the Field Calculator, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

In your regex matching pattern `([^_]*)$`, replace `*` (zero or more repetitions) by `+`  (one or more repetitions), then it works:

`regexp_replace('a_a_a_a_a','([^_]+)$','c\\1')` returns `'a_a_a_a_ca'`

---

##### Explanation

As [written in help](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace), the replacement string will "replace **any matching occurrences** of the supplied regular expression" (thus: not just one). Using the quantifier `*` (zero or more repetitions) finds in fact **two** matching patterns:

1. the last charcter `a` (one repetition of a non undscore character)
2. the end of the string after the last character: the "empty" end of the string: zero repetition of a non undscore character.

This becomes clear when the last character in the string is an underscore:

`regexp_replace('a_a_a_a_','([^_]*)$','c\\1')` returns `'a_a_a_a_c'`

So the expression gets the end of the string with a zero-repetition of a non-underscore character and replaces this by `c`. This might seem unexpected, but is logic. For this reason, stick to quantifier `+` to get at least one non-underscore character.